# How do you add a string to a Windows Form Label?

Tags: .net, string, winforms, c++-cli, stdstring

I tried doing it like this:

```
this->Label1->Text = "blah blah: " + GetSomething();
```

Where `GetSomething()` is a function that returns a string.

And the compiler gave me an error:

> "error C2679: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

```
string GetSomething()
{
    int id = 0;
    string Blah[] = {"test", "fasf", "hhcb"};

    return Blah[id];
}
```

Comment: can you show GetSomething code?

Comment: Did you #include <string>?

Comment: @RanEldan I just did that and another error showed up: error C2664: 'System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem::Text::set' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'System::String ^'

Comment: @billz I'm going to edit my post.

Comment: Did you using namespace std?

Comment: @RanEldan Yeah, I did

Comment: I'd like to mention I'm using VS Express 2012

Comment: Just a note, if you're trying to learn C++, you're going to have a lot of trouble using C++/CLI. It's a very different beast. You might want to stick with native unmanaged C++ until you're comfortable with it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you have at least two different string classes in play here.

WinForms (which you're apparently using for your GUI) uses the [.NET `System::String` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) everywhere. So the `Label.Text` property is getting/setting a .NET `System::String` object.

You say in the question that the `GetSomething()` method returns a `std::string` object. The `std::string` class is basically C++'s built-in string type, provided as part of the standard library.

Both classes are fine and serve their respective purposes well, but they're not directly compatible. That's what the (second attempt's) compiler message is trying to tell you:

> error C2664: `void System::Windows::Forms::Control::Text::set(System::String ^)` : cannot convert parameter 1 from `std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>` to `System::String ^`

Rewritten in plain English:

> error C2664: cannot convert the native `std::string` object passed as parameter 1 to a managed `System::String` object, required for the `Control::Text` property

The truth is, you really shouldn't mix the two string types. Since WinForms essentially forces its string type on you, that's the one I would standardize on, at least for any code that interacts with the GUI. So if possible, rewrite the `GetSomething()` method to return a `System::String` object; for example:

```
using namespace System;

...

String^ GetSomething()
{
    int id = 0;
    array <String^>^ Blah = gcnew array<String^>{"test", "fasf", "hhcb"};
    return Blah[id];
}

...

// use the return value of GetSomething() directly because the types match
this->Label1->Text = "blah blah: " + GetSomething();
```

If that's not possible (e.g. if this is library code that has little or nothing to do with your GUI), then you need to [explicitly convert one string type to the other](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235219.aspx):

```
#include <string>  // required to use std::string

...

std::string GetSomething()
{
    int id = 0;
    std::string Blah[] = {"test", "fasf", "hhcb"};
    return Blah[id];
}

...

// first convert the return value of GetSomething() to a matching type...
String^ something = gcnew String(GetSomething().c_str());

// ...then use it
this->label1->Text = "blah blah: " + something;
```

Comment: @Jan You should also be aware that you are mixing character sets and encodings. .NET uses Unicode/UTF-16 in most classes, (in particular,  System::String) and Unicode/UTF-8 in some classes (e.g., System.IO::Stream::StreamWriter(System::String ^)). Your C++ code is using an ANSI code page. When you "up-convert" to Unicode, you have to know that the source ANSI code page will be determined correctly. When you "down-convert" from Unicode, you have to know which ANSI code page you need and understand that there could be data loss. You could choose to use Unicode in C++ as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm *not* a C++/CLI wizard.

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
String^ GetSomething()
{
    Int32 id = 0;
    array <String^>^ Blah = gcnew array<String^>{"test", "fasf", "hhcb"};
    return Blah[id];
}
```

You are trying to mix CLI and non-CLI code. Windows Forms uses CLI. Do not use `std::string`. Instead use `System::String` (my code assumes that you have `using namespace System` at the top of your code. You'll also notice that I've replaced `int` with `System::Int32`, the managed equivalent.

The rest of your code is fine. I have placed the call to `GetSomething()` in a callback for a button:

```
private:
System::Void Button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    this->Label1->Text = "blah blah: " + GetSomething();
}
```